# Can't receive android.intent.action.USB_DGTL_MIC_PLUG

Tags: android, audio, usb, broadcastreceiver, microphone

Here is a funny one. Android 4.1.1. When a USB mic is connected (state = 1)/disconnected (state = 0) the following broadcast is sent:

```
VERBOSE/WiredAccessoryObserver(260): android.intent.action.USB_DGTL_MIC_PLUG: state: 1 name: usb_audio_capture
VERBOSE/AudioService(260): Broadcast Receiver: Got ACTION_USB_DGTL_MIC_PLUG, state = 1
```

Why does my broadcast receiver fail to recieve this? I do start the main activity manually.

```
<receiver android:name=".UsbMic" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USB_DGTL_MIC_PLUG" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>


public class UsbMic extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Test", "USB Mic");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find USB_DGTL_MIC_PLUG in the Android API as a system intent, so I can't verify it on my own (seems to be a device specific thing). Some intents can only be received, when you register a receiver from code instead of your manifest. Have you tried creating a custom reciever and starting it manually from your activity?

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.intent.action.USB_DGTL_MIC_PLUG");

receiver = new UsbMic();       
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Comment: Thank you Thrakbad, seems this is the way to go. I'll have to start the service first and register the broadcast receiver from it. This particular intent appears to be sticky too, so I'll know the sate of the mic on service start.

Comment: BTW talking about sticky broadcasts. I use `BATTERY_CHANGED` receiver registered at runtime in anoter apllication. When declared in the manifest it fails to fire. I checked this in the emulator by sending `power ac on/off`. The same command fires `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED/DISCONNECTED` receiver declared in the manifest. This broadcast isn't sticky. All this makes me think that sticky broadcasts are not meant (or just fail) to call receivers unless they are registered at runtime. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: I can't confirm if all sticky broadcasts can only be received from code, but there are some normal broadcasts that also can't be received when declared via the manifest (SCREEN_OFF, SCREEN_ON, and USER_PRESENT for example)

Answer (score 0):

> When a USB mic is connected (state = 1)/disconnected (state = 0) the following broadcast is sent

That's not necessarily the case, so you shouldn't rely on it.
 For example, the intent sent out when a host-powered USB audio accessory is detected on recent Qualcomm platforms is (IIRC) `android.intent.action.ANALOG_AUDIO_DOCK_PLUG`. This does not say anything about whether the accessory has a mic or not, because that check is done internally by the audio HAL and does not result in any intent being broadcast.

Comment: VERBOSE/WiredAccessoryObserver(260): android.intent.action.USB_DGTL_MIC_PLUG: state: 1 name: usb_audio_capture
VERBOSE/AudioService(260): Broadcast Receiver: Got ACTION_USB_DGTL_MIC_PLUG, state = 1 is from log cat. The AudioService seems to receive it. I actually observe this as I plug and unplug the mic. Why not me?

Comment: I don't know why you're not getting broadcast. My point was that there are Android devices that support USB microphones where this intent won't be sent out at all. So it's not useful as a generic way of detecting whether a USB mic has been attached.

Comment: Thank you Michael, my application is academic, for my own use. The mic I use will be married to to the device. Since the application is headless (no monitor) I hoped I could use this broadcast (noticed it accidently) to start/stop the service without a UI. Just out of curiosity where are these intents defined? Intellisense doesn't walk me there. Could it be the cause?